# The intersection of a submanifold with a submanifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Assume that $B$ is a manifold with dimension $2m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $N$ be sub-manifold with boundary ( denote the boundary by $\partial N$) of $B$ of dimension $m+1$ and let $M$ be a submanifold of $B$ (without boundary) of dimension $m$. Assume that $M \cap int(N) \neq \emptyset$ (where $int(N)$ denotes $N- \partial N$) ,$\partial N \cap M$ is exactly one point and $M$ is not fully contained in $N$.

**My question is**: is the following claim correct ?

> The intersection $M \cap N$ is 1-dimensional sub-manifold near the boundary $\partial N$ (that is there is $V$ a neighborhood of $\partial N$ in $B$ such that $V \cap M \cap N$ is a sub-manifold)

This seems to be correct if we assume that $M$ is a curve (one could convince himself by drawing and see that curves intersect the boundary of $N$ transversely) but what about the general case ?

**Edit**: Denote by $p$ the unique point of $M \cap \partial N$.  What if we assume that the intersection of $T_{p}N$ and $T_{p}M$ is one line ?

Comment: If $M$ is transverse to the boundary, then the intersection is submanifold with boundary, not a submanifold?

Comment: Do you have a proof on this statement ?

Comment: See Guillemin and Pollack's or Hirsch's differential topology texts.

Comment: Thank you very much.